# Effect of opposing electric charges on cells

Tags: cell-membrane, electrophysiology, electrical-stimulation

Is the affect on a cell between two negatively charged plates theoretically similar to between a positively and negatively charged plate?  In other words, would it induce charges on the inside and outside like in the other case:

[image]

But it would induce negative charges on the left and right outer sides of the membrane and positive charges on the inner sides:

[image]

Comment: Is there a context for asking this question?

Comment: Affect or effect? Sounds like the electricity has an effect. It follows the path of least resistance and most cells are generally insulative, blood and nerves probably look a bit like your illustrations.

Comment: Sorry about the title.  Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @Tom From the [help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". This seems like a toy physics problem rather than a biology one. I can ask at physics and see if they want it.

Comment: @ Bryan Krause: I see your point.  My apologies.